# An add-in in Excel for Mac cannot be updated

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-app

I have an add-in [10 Studio](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000139) in AppSource.

The current version (on 08/22/2019) is `1.5.1.0`. We load well this version in Excel for Windows:

[image]

However, when we load the same add-in from the add-in Store in Excel for Mac, it returns the version `1.3.0.0`.

[image]

It seems that the old version in Excel for Mac cannot be overridden. I followed [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac), cleared web cache by using the personality menu from the task pane, and remove everything in `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Caches/`. But the old version was still there and could not be overridden by the new version from the Store.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Did you find any answer useful?
Please post feedack.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try first removing the old version?

**How to uninstall an Add-in (Mac)**

If you wish to uninstall an Add-in completely, delete, move or rename the original Add-in file.

When ticking or unticking the Add-in, a message box will appear, asking for permission to delete the reference to the Add-in. Click Yes.

The Add-in will no longer appear in the list of Add-ins.

([Source](https://exceloffthegrid.com/install-uninstall-excel-add/))

Comment: That source is not regarding to JavaScript Add-ins.

Comment: @SoftTimur - Even if there is a tag office-js, I did not understand that the OP referred *exclusively* to JavaScript.